# Get calculated ratio value from data-attribute string

Tags: javascript, html

I got some aspect ratio value in a data-attribute like

```
<li data-ratio="4/3">4:3</li>
```

On a click I need to get the correct value - not the string, like I get it with this:

```
'click li': function(event) {
    var ratio = $(event.currentTarget).attr('data-ratio');
}
```

I don't know if I have to change the format of the data-attribute or just do some convertion on the result - like:

```
var value = $(event.currentTarget).attr('data-ratio').split('/');
ratio = value[0] / value[1];
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it give you what you were expecting? Are they ALWAYS going to be division?

Comment: If you're the one controlling the `data-ratio` value, wouldn't it be wiser to encode is as a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`.split()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) will return an array of strings. Although JavaScript will sometimes handle the type coercion, you should still convert these strings to numbers. You can use the [`parseInt()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) in order to retrieve the number from the string:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/cm826g0n/)

```
$('li').on('click', function(event) {
  var values = $(this).attr('data-ratio').split('/');
  var ratio = parseInt(values[0], 10) / parseInt(values[1], 10);

  // ...
});
```

Comment: What would happen if `data-ratio=""`?

Comment: @user3142695 It will return `NaN`. What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I can not good understand what you are looking for, can you please check this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('data-ratio'))
  })
})
```

Have a look at this fiddle and tell me what you need if this is wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/